# How to Map a function on just one entry in a list?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have been learning to use Map more (to become more functional programmer). It looks like Map wants a list as the expression to apply the function to. If the expression is not a list, then it is not happy.

I use NumberForm in this example to illustrate what I mean:

I can Map NumberForm on the whole list ok:

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, data]
```

But if I try to Map it to some specific element in the list, say the first one in the above, it does not work

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, data[[1]] ]
```

The result returned is NOT formatted. Same as original data. i.e I get back '1' and not '1.00' as in the other examples.

To solve, I added extra `{}`

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, {data[[1]]} ]
```

it works now, (just need to remove the `{}` from the result using `First`).

So I thought, then why not add this extra `{}` all the time and remove it in the end?
This way, I do not have to worry if what I am Map'ing function to happened to be not a list like in the above example?

So, my examples will all becomes like this:

```
data = {1, 2, 3}
First@Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, { data } ]
First@Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, { data[[1]] } ]
```

This way, code will works on everything and I do not have to make special check before using Map if what I happened to be applying Map to is a list or not.

**Question is: Does the the above look an OK solution for the experts, or is there a better way to handle this?**

Comment: I have to confess, I don't understand what your motivation is for asking this question. Why would you ever try to `Map` on to something which is not a list?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky One may eventually want to `Map` on something else than a list, but this is rather rare and anyways done in situations different from the one discussed in this question. A typical example would be something like `Map[f, myContainerA[myContainerB[1, 2, 3], 
  myContainerC[4, 5, 6]], {2}]`, although in cases like that I usually use rules.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, but does my approach not answer it? If not, could you try to explain in a different way what you want? It seems to me that my suggestion does exactly what you want.

Comment: I see you accepted acl's answer.  Be careful with the `map` function he shows, just as I said for my use of levelspec `{-1}`.  If you use `map[f, Sqrt[2]]` you will see that this may not be what you want.  I still believe there is a deeper issue of method implicit in your question that has not been well addressed.

Comment: To say that a different way, you asked: *"Does the above look an OK solution for the experts, or is there a better way to handle this?"*  I say no, it does not look like an OK solution **generally**, and neither does acl's `map` or my `Map[f, x, {-1}]`.  Would you please consider adding some use context to your question, that we may better recommend an approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only happens to work because `NumberForm` works on lists:

```
NumberForm[{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2}]
```

gives

```
{1.00, 2.00, 3.00}
```

`Map[f, {{a, b, c}}]` simply maps `f` onto `First[{{a,b,c}}]`, namely, onto `{a,b,c}`; so you get `f[{a,b,c}]`.

So unfortunately adding `{}` will not work in general.

A simple way to do this is to define

```
ClearAll[map]
map[f_, head_[els__]] := Map[f, head[els]]
map[f_, el_] := f[el]
```

whence

```
map[f, {a, b, c}]
map[f, a]
```

give

```
{f[a], f[b], f[c]}
f[a]
```

However this does not allow for the `Map[f,expr,levelspec]` form (which however is easy enough to implement).

This also works in this case:

```
map[f, g[a, b, c]] == Map[f, g[a, b, c]]
(*
True
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm not understanding your intent here, but if you're looking `Map` a function on just a particular entry in a list, then [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAt.html) is the function you're looking for. Example:

```
MapAt[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, data, 1]
Out[1]= {1.00,2,3}
```

Here, the function has been applied to only the first element in the list.

Comment: Good point, I thought he just wanted a way to be able to say `Map[f,l]` and have it work whether `l` is list-like or atomic. But maybe your interpretation is correct.

Comment: Actually I know about MapAt, but then it is leads to the same thing. I have to use MapAt if I want to apply NumberForm to one entry, and then use Map if I want to apply NumberForm to a list. So back to square one :) The reason I asked about adding {} is to see if I can just use one method for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few different questions

1. What are the different ways to `Map`?  Not surprisingly, because lists are fundamental to the operation of Mathematica, there are many ways to transform them.  However, there isn't any direct way that I can see to tell Mathematica that, given `f` and `{l1, l2, ...}` to give me `{f@l1, l2, ...}`.  If you want to apply `f` to the first element of `l` (for example, to test before applying f to all of l) you can also do `f/@l[[1;;1]]`. (edit @yoda mentions that `MapAt` has this behavior, one can specify a set of positions where one should map).
2. How to deal with an operand that implements the Composite pattern (ie, is either an element of type t or a list of elements of type t)?  The natural way to do this in Mathematica is to give your operator the `Listable` attribute.  Then if we define: `f[a_AtomicType]`, `f[a:{_AtomicType..}]` gives the results of `f/@a`

Edit -- Actually, given `f[a_AtomicType]:=something`, `f[a_List]` gives the results of `f/@a` even if some elements of a don't have head `AtomicType` -- ie Listable functions don't verify that all elements of the list have a transformation rule in terms of `f`.  If you care about this you would need to separately define `f[a:{_AtomicType..}]:=f/@a` and not make your function `Listable`.

Also, @Nasser, it looks like the behavior in your first example is because `Map[f,a_AtomicType]` returns `a`.  Also note that `Map` can map over expressions with any head, not just `List`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an odd question.  Why write `First@Map[f, { x } ]` when you can just write `f @ x`?

How does it come to be that the second argument of `Map` may be either form?

Perhaps you would find value in mapping by levels from the end:

```
Map[f, {x, y, z}, {-1}]

Map[f, x, {-1}]
```

Be careful with this, as if the list elements are not atomic, you will get unexpected results.

Alternatively, you might write:

```
data = {1, 2, 3};

data /. n_?NumberQ :> NumberForm[n, {3, 2}]

data[[1]] /. n_?NumberQ :> NumberForm[n, {3, 2}]
```